# VBScript create list, split list items and trim them

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to create code that would add variables to list. Then it would split all of list elements by `:`, returning only the second part. In the end all returned strings would be trimmed.

To give you better understanding let me show you an example:

1. Add "a : b " and " c : d " to the list.
2. Split elements so only "b " and "d " are returned.
3. Trim "b " and "d ".

So far I have came up with something like this but it doesn't work and I have no idea why.

```
Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
list.Add "bob : kid"
list.Add "ryan : alex"
list.Add "kate : andy"
list.Add "alice : mandy"
For Each item In list
    Dim item As String
    Dim words As String() = item.Split(New Char() {":"c})
    For Each word In words
        WScript.Echo word
    Next
Next
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a useful problem description. Describe the problem, including error messages and the exact location in the code where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because it's not valid VBScript. You have several issues:

- VBScript doesn't support typed variable declarations (`Dim var As Type`). Use `Dim var` if you want to explicitly define a variable. Note, however, that in VBScript defining variables is only required when you put `Option Explicit` at the beginning of your script.
- VBScript doesn't support combined declaration and definition of variables (`Dim var = value`). You need two separate statements for defining a variable and assigning a value to it. The two statements can be put in one line by separating them with a colon (`Dim var : var = value`), but they're still two separate statements.
- In VBScript string is a primitive data type. VBScript strings are not objects with properties. For splitting a string use the `Split()` function.
- Don't re-define your loop variable inside your loop.

Change your loop to something like this and it should do what you want:

```
For Each item In list
    Dim words : words = Split(item, ":")
    For Each word In words
        WScript.Echo Trim(word)
    Next
Next
```

If you want just the second element from each split item you'd do something like this:

```
Dim words : words = Split(item, ":")
WScript.Echo Trim(words(1))
```

or like this:

```
WScript.Echo Trim(Split(item, ":")(1))
```

Comment: Your loop worked just fine, thank you for helping me. However I still don't know how to return only every second element. If you know could you please add it to your response?